# what is the Difference between ./bitcoind and $ ./bitcoind -daemon?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

I was trying to interact with bitcoin network with JSON RPC commands, So I referred to the bitcoin wiki page https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Java it shows to run the bitcoin using 'bitcoind -daemon' command. but another page of bitcoin wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin suggest running the node using './bitcoind' command.so
 What is the difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two commands?

`./bitcoind` - runs bitcoin node in the **foreground**.

`./bitcoind -daemon` - runs bitcoin node as daemon.

> What is `daemon`?

In multitasking computer operating systems, a `daemon` is a computer program that runs as a **background** process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user.

Comment: so the bitcoin -daemon command also download the blockchain data in the background, right?

Comment: `bitcoin -daemon` runs bitcoin node in the background.

Comment: @Akshay Operationally, the two are identical. The only difference is whether it runs in the background or not.